# change event not firing from external script on react page

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have loaded my script as an external script in a 3rd party site that is on react.

```
  $(function () {
    $('#shopify-section-product .selector-wrapper').change(function(e) {
       console.log('change!!!');
    });
  });
```

The above change is not firing, I had put a debugger but nothing working out. Strange thing though, if I put the `change code` in the console, it logging correctly.

Is it something blocked by reactjs onChange? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is (or are) the element with class `.selector-wrapper`?

Comment: Can you provide more insight on how you actually using it in Reactjs? Are you sure it is wrapped in `useEffect` hook?

Comment: @harry site (not owned by the company but is a client whom we gave our script) is already using react.js, And on the product page of the site, I have added my own script which is using plain js and jquery. 

In the script, there is one change listener (like above) which listened to the size change. The above is working fine with the console but when I put the debugger in the script control doesn't go there nor does console print.

Comment: `.selector-wrapper` is the closest grandparent node class of the div which has the sizes (in li's as its child).

I have checked already on size change the change is fired which can be listened to by the safe closest parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#shopify-section-product .selector-wrapper', function(e) {
       console.log('change!!!');
    });
});
```